# PLSQL exception handler for invalid argument type

Tags: exception, plsql

So I have 2 PL/SQL files: p401 contains the function to be called (update_item_cost) by P403.

**P401 code:**

```
  CREATE or replace PROCEDURE update_item_cost (iItemId INTEGER, fNewcost NUMBER) AS
  fCurCost NUMBER (10,2);

  BEGIN
         SELECT item_cost INTO fCurCost FROM pitem
         WHERE item_id = iItemId; 
         UPDATE pitem SET item_cost = fNewCost
         WHERE item_id = iItemId;
         COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
              INSERT INTO pitem_audit VALUES (iItemId, 'Invalid Item Identifier');
              COMMIT;
         WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
              INSERT INTO pitem_audit VALUES (iItemId, 'You entered an invalid number');
              COMMIT;
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
              ROLLBACK;
              INSERT INTO pitem_audit VALUES (iItemId, 'Miscellaneous error.');
              COMMIT;
  END update_item_cost;
  /
```

**P403 code:**

```
 DECLARE
        item_ident number;
        cost number;
 BEGIN  
         update_item_cost (&item_ident, &cost);
 END;
 /
```

There are two tables: **pitem** (has all the items and description and cost of item), and **pitem_audit** (contains the error message). 
Let's say, for example, the user entered a string instead of number for item_ident (i.e.'1x'). So the exception handler will catch the error and return the error message by **inserting a line into pitem_audit table as below:**

```
   ITEM_ID     MESSAGE
               You entered an invalid number
```

I tried **VALUE_ERROR** (and also **INVALID_NUMBER**) as the exception handler but none of them work. As soon as I execute p403 and the function (update_item_cost) was called, I got this error:

```
    SQL> DECLARE
            item_ident number;
            cost number;
         BEGIN
            update_item_cost (&item_ident, &cost);
         END;
         /
        Enter value for item_ident: '1x'
        Enter value for cost: 250
        old   5:        update_item_cost (&item_ident, &cost);
        new   5:        update_item_cost ('1x', 250);
        DECLARE
        *
        ERROR at line 1:
        ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
        ORA-06512: at line 5
```

So the question is why did the VALUE_ERROR or INVALID_NUMBER not work, and how do I fix it? I want it to work just like the **NO_DATA_FOUND** exception, which inserts a line into **pitem_audit** table when it can't find the item in the database.

```
    ITEM_ID     MESSAGE
                Invalid Item Identifier
```

Thanks a lot, and I'm sorry if this is too lengthy :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the type conversion exception occurs in P403, when the user is prompted for values, before `PROCEDURE update_item_cost` is called, hence the PROC does not get the opportunity to handle the exception in the exception handler.

Proc `update_item_cost` expects two numeric inputs `(iItemId INTEGER,fNewcost NUMBER)`.

There are a couple of options

- Move, the exception handling to an outer proc such as `P403` - this would make most sense as you are now separating the concerns of prompting and validating user input, from doing the update itself.
- Change the type of `iItemId` in `P401` to a `VARCHAR` or other character type (which would support any user input), and doing the parsing to Number there.